# Создание задачи по расписанию

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

```
@Scheduled(timeUnit = TimeUnit.DAYS, fixedDelay = 7)
```

Можно ли создать выполнение задачи каждое воскресенье ?

Comment: `@Scheduled(cron = "0 0 1 * * SUN")`

Comment: Можно.  Есть такой обьект Сalendar